# Working on a HardBrick for Breakout the game

Tags: java

I am just getting into object oriented programming and have created the game Breakout, but am now trying to get specialty bricks i.e. TeleportBrick, SpeedupBrick, and HardBrick.

The HardBrick is tricking me. I attempted to insert a count++ everytime a HardBrick was hit and once the count++ equaled 3, return null at that brick's particular spot in the array. For some reason, the count++ is occurring when other bricks - not just the HardBrick - are hit.

My assumption was other bricks in the array would not trigger this hit(Ball b) function because this hit method in question is inside of the HardBrick class, not the ColorBrick or Brick classes, and will only affect the designated HardBrick's.

Code I'm working on:

```
@Override
    public void hit(Ball b) {
        // Figure out which way to bounce the ball and remove the brick from the game
        if (b.lasty > b.y || b.y <= y + Main.bheight || b.lastx <= x || b.lastx >= x + Main.bwidth) {
            b.yv = -b.yv;
            b.xv = -b.xv;
            HBhitcount++; 
            if (HBhitcount++ == 3) {
                bricks[i][j] = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `HBhitcount`? A non-static member variable to the HardBlock class, or a static variable (note: it should probably be non-static)? You might need to provide a few more classes of HardBrick, and the super-class Brick too for us to help — it would also be useful to know what `bricks` is. And stick with camelCase for variable names and PascalCase for class names in Java :)

Comment: also note that in `HBhitcount++; if (HBhitcount++ == 3)` you are incrementing `HBhitcount` twice.

Comment: @LorisSecuro that was all it was haha. Always nice getting another pair of eyes to look at code. Thank you.